# Python combination and iteration two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, iteration

DataFrame n.1

| COL1 | COL2 | RESULT (sum/count) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 1 |  |

dataframe 2:

[image: dataFramen.2]

I would like to propose you for advice, I can't create the codes of iteration and combination for the computing operation:

Dataframe no.1 represents a combination of values from (0-9).

Dataframe No.2 represents a time series of hourly values.

I need to take a value from Datafram No. 1 (COL1), multiply by this value column Calc_2 in Dataframe no.2, then deduct this resulting value from Calc_1 and perform Sum/Count operations in the resulting field and write the result back to Dataframe no to Result. And do this gradually on all lines.

i tried it over 2 for cycles but no result

Comment: please provide the second dataframe in a reproducible format (text) and with only a few rows, also provide the matching expected output

Comment: Please show what you tried.